# Какой тип коннектора использовать для подключении гибкой мембраны к пинам?

Tags: arduino, железо

Я модифицирую стандартный инженерный калькулятор и хочу использовать его родную клавиатуру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она подключалась к калькулятору по гибкой плате с 20 проводов выходов, на нем нет отсоединяемого коннектора.
Можете подсказать какой тип коннектора нужно использовать для подключении этой платы к пинам ардуино, при условии что я не хочу вручную впаивать каждый выход к отдельному пину.

Я так понимаю что можно проткнуть эту ленту коннектором в 20 пинов "папа", учитывая что шаг между проводами 1 мм, но я не знаю насколько это будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Протыкание вам точно не поможет.

В идеале, взять кусов платы к которой это коннектилось и подпаяться к дорожкам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Но раз уж вы ее уже отрезали, то снимайте изолирующее покрытие и просто прижимайте к пятакам на макетке (принцип аналогичен, через резинку).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете посоветовать чем можно снимать изолирующее покрытие, ибо мне кажется оно слишком тонкое для обычных стрипперов

Comment: @Rooter Сам не пробовал, но: для начала проверить есть ли оно вообще (например, мультиметром). Дальше посмотрел бы в сторону растворителей и/или наждачек (от 1000 и тоньше) или на крайний случай аккуратно "поскрести" лезвием скальпеля/резака.

Comment: @Rooter для улучшения контакта, перед прижимом, можно еще добавить графита (с мягкого карандаша).

Comment: Есть ли смысл перед снятием изоляции немного нагреть термофеном и потом аккуратно скрябать или это ток хуже сделает?

Comment: @Rooter мне кажется не стоит, т.к. обычная электроника градусов до 70 обычно просто работает, а выше - пластиковая основа будет плавиться.